# Integrating nodejs and php using docker containers

Tags: php, node.js, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I am creating an Educational website having three microservices, which I would be integrating with the help of Docker containers. The three microservices are namely

```
User Microservice : Takes care of User login (Technologies used: MongoDB, Nodejs and EJS)
Course Microservice : Allows a teacher to add courses (Technologies used: MySql and PHP)
Payment Microservice : Basic Payment Gateway (Technologies used: Nodejs and EJS)
```

Now, I am trying to integrate the user microservice with the course microservice for which I have written two dockerfiles.

**Dockerfile.web**

```
FROM node:8
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Copy app source code
COPY . .
#Expose port and start application
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**Dockerfile.course**

```
FROM php:7.4.9-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql
# Install app dependencies
# Copy app source code
COPY . . 
#Expose port and start application
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "php", "-S" ]
```

I have used a docker-compose file to integrate these services.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.web
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
  course: 
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.course
    ports:
      - "2000:2000"
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=moe-mysql-app
      - MYSQL_USER=abc
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=abcd
      - MYSQL_DB=moe_db
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
      - MYSQL_USER=abc
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=abcd 
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sample_db
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.7
    links: 
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "30002:80"
```

Now, when I run `docker-compose up` I can see the User microservice running successfully. However, the php page doesn't turn up. Following is the route (coded in nodejs) which I am using to access the php page.

```
# Route index.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { ensureAuthenticated, forwardAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');

// Welcome Page
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index.php'));

// Dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>
  res.render('dashboard', {
    user: req.user
  })
);

router.get('/course.php', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>
  res.render('course')
);

module.exports = router;
```

Here, index.php and course.php are the pages which keep on loading and don't give the intended result.

According to me, since I am routing the php code through my nodejs route, the php page is not being shown. But I don't know how to exactly mitigate this issue. I am a novice in using Docker containers, any help would be appreciated. Please consider correcting any mistake in the above code.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you get any response if you try and access the PHP docker container directly?

Comment: No, I dont get any response. Actually the container gets exited before showing up anything. However, I tried to directly access the Nodejs container now, even that gets exited, and does not show any output, whereas when I use ```docker-compose up``` Node container works perfectly well.

Comment: Try removing the last 2 lines in your php dockerfile.  It should be ports 80/443 if any and the apache server should run at startup.  The try accessing this container on port 80 (you can expose the ports but it may be better to have to use this directly).

Comment: I tried this. It did not work as a part of container. The output on port 80 was phpmyadmin, which I suspect turned up because I had Xampp installed in my local machine (as I could see all the databases which I had)

Comment: If you don't expose the port, you have to access the content using the IP address of the container.

Comment: There are loads of How To's out there to get started running a php app in a docker container.